# NotesDocumentCollection returns only 1 Document

Tags: lotusscript

I'm having a problem with my lotusscript-agent I wrote.

Basically I'm just doing something like this:

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim coll As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim key As String

key = "keyvalue" 
Set db = s.Currentdatabase
Set view = db.GetView("MyView")
Set coll = view.Getalldocumentsbykey(key,True)
...
```

This is very simple, but somehow coll only returns 1 document.
When I look into MyView, I see 2 documents with the same key. My Agent is set to target all documents in the database and triggered in the Actions-menu.

I might just be very stupid, I guess the solution is pretty simple.
Please help :(

Comment: Have you checked if there are maybe leading and trailing spaces in the keyvalue of your documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the first column (where your `key` applies to) of your view is sorted. Sorting direction is arbitrary. If the first column of your lookup view is not sorted, then searching won't work properly.

[image: view column properties]

**UPDATE**

If your view contains more columns which affect on the search, then make additional hidden view with only one **sorted** column that represents the search key value. And use this hidden view.

Use of visible views for searching via script is not a good idea, because end-user may ask a developer to rearrange columns or add/remove columns to fit to the updated business needs. And if your code relies on the visible view, then it will stop working.

To avoid this issue use hidden views for searching purposes from your script. To make a view hidden enclose it's name in brackets. For instance to make view `SomeView` to hidden, rename it to `(SomeView)`

Comment: Thank you for that idea. The problem was not the first column, but the columns after that. I guess the columns after the first column cant be sorted by categories or sorted at all.

Comment: Might be easier to just make a new view that contains the docs you want in a simple manner and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

A key in "GetAllDocumentsByKey" can be an array and contain values for ALL sorted/categorized columns in your view. If there is another category in your view and you omit that key, then GetAllDocumentsByKey will only get documents for the FIRST sub- category. If you need to ignore the second column, then make it sorted only, not categorized.

This is the reason, why for Lookups you always create a hidden separate view. That one can be designed to fulfill the needs of the lookups without tampering with what the user wants to see